# VS2010 C++ MFC Multiple project solution override automatic linking of dll project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc, linker

I have an MFC solution with 17 sub-projects.  I just recently added another dll project and cannot get the executable to link to the renamed version of the library.  In the settings for the dll projects in the solution, debug builds all have a 'D' appended to the output name to signify that it's the debug version.  In some cases, we do that by changing the TargetName to $(ProjectName)D, and in other cases a post build event copies it from the build directory to the lib directory and renames it appending the 'D'.  For this project, when I compile the dll I get the two files as expected: MultiLangD.lib and MultiLangD.dll. This is the linker command line for the dll project:

```
/OUT:".\Debug\MultiLangD.dll" /NOLOGO /DLL /MANIFEST 
/ManifestFile:".\Debug\MultiLangD.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG 
/PDB:"C:\WorkSpaces\WorkSpace_CFFT_II_i18n\CFFT_i18n_MBCS\CFFT\MultiLang\Debug\MultiLangD.pdb" 
/PGD:"C:\WorkSpaces\WorkSpace_CFFT_II_i18n\CFFT_i18n_MBCS\CFFT\MultiLang\Debug\MultiLangD.pgd" 
/TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\Debug\MultiLangD.lib" /MACHINE:X86 
/ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

This is the compiler command line for the dll project:

```
/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_AFXEXT" /D
"_MULTILANGDLL" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /D "_AFXDLL" /Gm
/EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR- /Yu"StdAfx.h" 
/Fp".\Debug\MultiLangD.pch" /Fa".\Debug\" /Fo".\Debug\" /Fd".\Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd 
/analyze- /errorReport:queue
```

In the executable project I list MultiLangD.lib as an additional dependency to the linker, set "Link Library Dependencies" to no, and "Use Library Dependency Inputs" to yes.  The MultiLang dll project is not set as a project dependency to the executable.  Nevertheless, in the debug build, I get an error because the linker cannot find MultiLang.lib.  This is the linker command line of the executable project:

```
/OUT:".\Debug\WinGFApp.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"..\Lib"
/LIBPATH:"..\Student\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (March 2009)\Lib\x86" 
"MultiLangD.lib" "datastored.lib" "shlwapi.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "MdxReadd.lib" "winmm.lib" 
"dxguid.lib" "dxerr9.lib" "dinput8.lib" "Messagingd.lib" "dtccd.lib" "Version.lib" 
"SerialTCIMD.lib" "geosrvdll.lib" "NetworkUIDMD.lib" "amp2.lib" "idmmib.lib" 
"vmfr2.lib" "d3dx9.lib" "comsuppwd.lib" "vmf_net_db.lib" "jvmfd.lib" 
/NODEFAULTLIB:"libc" /NODEFAULTLIB:"libcd" /NODEFAULTLIB:"libci" /MANIFEST 
/ManifestFile:".\Debug\WinGFApp.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:".\Debug/CFFTInstrD.pdb" 
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
 /PGD:"C:\WorkSpaces\WorkSpace_CFFT_II_i18n\CFFT_i18n_MBCS\CFFT\Instructor\Debug\WinGFApp.pg
d" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

This is the compiler command line:

```
/I"." /I"..\Instructor\csw" /I"..\Instructor\CFFTInstr" /I"..\Student\common" 
/I"..\Student\Messaging" /I"..\Student\geotrans" /I"..\SerialTcim" /I"..\AudioServer" 
/I"..\NetworkUIDM\UIDM_Include" /I"..\NetworkUIDM\UIDM_JVMF" /I"..\NetworkUIDM" 
/I"..\Instructor\cas" /I"..\Jvmf" /I"..\Instructor\JvmfGui" /I"..\Instructor\JvmfCff" 
/I"..\NLOS" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (March 2009)\Include" /Zi 
/nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "NO_MSGS" /D 
"INSTRUCTOR" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES" 
/D "_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0600" /D "_MBCS" /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 
/MTd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yu"stdafx.h" /Fp".\Debug/WinGFApp.pch" 
/Fa".\Debug/" /Fo".\Debug/" /Fd".\Debug/" /FR".\Debug\" /Gd /analyze-/errorReport:queue
```

When I open the .vcxproj file in np++ and search for MultiLang.lib it only appears as a dependency in the release build, while in the debug build settings MultiLangD.lib is listed.  This is the debug settings ItemDefinitionGroup node from the .vcxproj file:

```
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
<Midl>
  <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
  <MkTypLibCompatible>true</MkTypLibCompatible>
  <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
  <TargetEnvironment>Win32</TargetEnvironment>
  <TypeLibraryName>.\Debug/WinGFApp.tlb</TypeLibraryName>
  <HeaderFileName>
  </HeaderFileName>
</Midl>
<ClCompile>
  <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
  <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>.;..\Instructor\csw;..\Instructor\CFFTInstr;..\Student\common;..\Student\Messaging;..\Student\geotrans;..\SerialTcim;..\AudioServer;..\NetworkUIDM\UIDM_Include;..\NetworkUIDM\UIDM_JVMF;..\NetworkUIDM;..\Instructor\cas;..\Jvmf;..\Instructor\JvmfGui;..\Instructor\JvmfCff;..\NLOS;C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft DirectX SDK %28March 2009%29\Include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
  <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;NO_MSGS;INSTRUCTOR;_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE;_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES;_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
  <BasicRuntimeChecks>EnableFastChecks</BasicRuntimeChecks>
  <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebug</RuntimeLibrary>
  <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
  <PrecompiledHeaderFile>stdafx.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
  <PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile>.\Debug/WinGFApp.pch</PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile>
  <AssemblerListingLocation>.\Debug/</AssemblerListingLocation>
  <ObjectFileName>.\Debug/</ObjectFileName>
  <ProgramDataBaseFileName>.\Debug/</ProgramDataBaseFileName>
  <BrowseInformation>true</BrowseInformation>
  <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
  <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
  <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
</ClCompile>
<ResourceCompile>
  <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
  <Culture>0x0409</Culture>
</ResourceCompile>
<Link>
  <AdditionalDependencies>MultiLangD.lib;datastored.lib;shlwapi.lib;ws2_32.lib;MdxReadd.lib;winmm.lib;dxguid.lib;dxerr9.lib;dinput8.lib;Messagingd.lib;dtccd.lib;Version.lib;SerialTCIMD.lib;geosrvdll.lib;NetworkUIDMD.lib;amp2.lib;idmmib.lib;vmfr2.lib;d3dx9.lib;comsuppwd.lib;vmf_net_db.lib;jvmfd.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
  <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
  <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>..\Lib;..\Student\lib;C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft DirectX SDK %28March 2009%29\Lib\x86;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
  <IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries>libc;libcd;libci;%(IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries)</IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries>
  <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
  <ProgramDatabaseFile>.\Debug/CFFTInstrD.pdb</ProgramDatabaseFile>
  <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
  <TargetMachine>MachineX86</TargetMachine>
</Link>
<Bscmake>
  <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
  <OutputFile>Debug/CFFTInstrD.bsc</OutputFile>
</Bscmake>
<PostBuildEvent>
  <Message>Copy Executable</Message>
  <Command>if not exist ..\exec mkdir ..\exec
    copy debug\WinGFApp.exe ..\exec\CFFTInstrD.exe
  </Command>
</PostBuildEvent>
<ProjectReference />
<ProjectReference>
  <UseLibraryDependencyInputs>true</UseLibraryDependencyInputs>
  <LinkLibraryDependencies>false</LinkLibraryDependencies>
</ProjectReference>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Unfortunately, all the executables and dlls generated are copied to a single directory as post build events, so I have to follow the "append D" naming convention to avoid overwriting artifacts from other builds.  I'm not sure why none of the other dll projects in the build have this problem.  I am obviously missing something here but cannot figure out what it is.  Can someone please enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong and how to accomplish this.  Thanks.

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that I have also tried adding a reference to the project in Common Properties->Framework and References.

[image: Reference settings]

Also, while the compilation is under way I see `Automatically linking with MultiLang.lib` scroll by.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working.  I removed the reference and set Linker->General->Ignore Import Library to Yes.  I left everything else the same and now it compiles and links just fine.